# Friends and relationship searches with sphinx (like friends of friends) for social networks

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I was looking for a solution to search friends by an exact name or a prefix of their first or last name. my requirement is something similar to this link. [Sphinx vs. MySql - Search through list of friends (efficiency/speed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762147/sphinx-vs-mysql-search-through-list-of-friends-efficiency-speed?answertab=votes#tab-top)
but the post does not explain the how to do it approach. It does say that searching across relationship through sphinx is not recommended. Can anyone please suggest whether i should use any of the following approaches or an entirely different approach. Also i am looking for high speed and scalability for say more than a million records

DB structure is something similar.

InnoDB

table1- users: uid, fname, lname, city, country, picurl, status (picurl & status may change anytime and sphinx is not realtime & just say or imagine that even 10 minutes lag is not acceptable in my design for these two fields.)

table2- friends: uid,fid

goal is to search: all friends of "uid 11" having prefix 'tony' in their fname or lname or full name and pull out their details.

- Approach 1:

Sphinx: search on uid, fname, lname (attributes: city, country)

a) Do a mysql search to pull out the friend ids of "uid 11" & store in array X

b) then do sphinx search for 'tony*' filtered docid by the array X.

c) then again do a mysql search to pull the realtime fields like picurl,status for each of the matching friendids.

OR

- Approach 2:

Sphinx: search on uid, fname, lname (attributes: city, country) 
+ MVA: friendids (MVA to store all friend ids)

a)search sphinx for 'tony*' filtered by MVA that contains uid '11'

b)then again do a mysql search to pull the realtime fields like picurl,status for each of the matching friendids.

- Approach 3:

No Sphinx

a)Mysql search friends of "uid 11" where fname like 'tony%' OR lname like 'tony%' OR CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) LIKE 'tony stark%' OR CONCAT(lname, ' ', fname) LIKE 'tony stark%'and pullout the details in the same query join
(From the other posts this seems to be low on performance for large number of records)

- Approach 4:

  Any suggestions?

---

PS: my next challenge is to search for friends of friends and so the question header..

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend **Approach 2**

But for Approach 4 - would porbably be to use a dedicated Graph database. (or a dedicated [engine](http://openquery.com/products/graph-engine) for mysql) - for just prefix searches, you dont strictly need something like sphinx.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a direction to work on. So Approach4 should be better than Approach2 rite? Also would it be better to use neo4j along with mysql or use a mysql engine like oqgraph that you have mentioned(is it the best mysql engine?). (i ask this because i read that neo4j is persistent and oqgraph not.) Also which of these would be more efficient for a large database. Also can you please provide some good links for understanding when not to use RDBMS cause there seem to be a sea of no-sql options out there. After reading all these it seems mysql really is not that great with large DBs.

Comment: I mean RDBMS dont seem to be good with large Data. did not mean to pin point mysql as such.