# mysql speed up search query

Tags: mysql

I have an article table with 2 columns

```
Id INT(4) PK autoincrement
Description VARCHAR(250)
(and more columns)
```

This table contains 500.000 records and is a INNODB table.
Now I want to search an article like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM article (description like '%cannon%');
```

It takes almost a second to execute ..

What can I to to make this faster?

I have alread an index on the Description column

Comment: There is a few things that you could do, one would be to add a primary key to the table to ensure that it can be indexed correctly, and then add indexes on the table to speed up the query.

Also,

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM article WHERE description LIKE '%cannon%';

Comment: index on description does not help

Comment: `like '%cannon%'` kills the index.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081998/optimization-of-mysql-search-using-like-and-wildcards

Comment: The best optimization possible is if you use `COUNT(1)` instead of `COUNT(*)`. The `%canon%` negates any other kind of optimization.

Comment: yes, if you are using 5.6, try fulltext search  -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: if you have some trick to divide description filed that you can improve you table struct: for example: `description = date , about , subject, bla .... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries with `like '%cannon%'` are very hard to optimize. No, indexes can't help you. Maybe full-text search can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider adding fulltext index on description:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

And then use:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM article 
WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST ('cannon' WITH QUERY EXPANSION);
```

Comment: the storage engine is innodb

Comment: my dear, the support of full-text search is 5.6 onwards, yet, you paste a documentation of 5.0