# MySql LIKE '%keyword%' wildcards on starting & ending - work around to use index

Tags: mysql

MySql does not use index on LIKE if wildcards are on both start and end.

Is there a work around for this query so it will use index:

```
SELECT * FROM Company WHERE Name LIKE '%ad%'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimization of MySQL search using "like" and wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081998/optimization-of-mysql-search-using-like-and-wildcards)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Improve Search Performance with wildcards (%%)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905125/mysql-improve-search-performance-with-wildcards)

Comment: Read my presentation [Full Text Search Throwdown](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use fulltext search for such things: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple, don't use index at the start of the `LIKE` expression.

Adjust your data accordingly - use extra columns if you have to.

Comment: Thanks! But I need to have it on both start and end. I also have tons of data. Well I think there is no way to speed this search.

Comment: Correct, it's not possible, unless you can find a way to split your data into a new column and search on that.

Answer (score 0):

Put both cases in the where clause with OR operator:

```
SELECT * FROM Company WHERE ( Name LIKE '%ad' OR Name LIKE 'ad%' )
```