# To reduce Mysql Query CPU utilization

Tags: mysql, cpu-usage

I have query which uses **like** with `"%search_pattern%"` which is taking high CPU utilization if i hit 5-6 parallel request, my table has data around 30 Million.

Can any alternative methods or algorithm be used to optimize that?

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_DETAILS U WHERE U.NAME LIKE %JOHN%';
```

CPU Utilization is going to 700%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimization of MySQL search using "like" and wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081998/optimization-of-mysql-search-using-like-and-wildcards)

Answer (score 1):

When you use **LIKE '%JOHN%'** mysql cant use a index and must compare each ROW with the String. The only way to use a Index is use **LIKE 'JOHN%'** ´. look if a index on **NAME**