# Doing a mysql like %term% on 1B records (with indexed field)

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have the following query that I'm using and was wondering if it would work performantly, or whether I should use ElasticSearch from the start:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  entity_access 
  JOIN entity ON (entity.id=entity_access.entity_id)
WHERE
  user_id = 144
  AND name LIKE '%format%'
```

The `entity_access` table will have about a billion results. But each user should have 5k entries max. My thinking was that a `LIKE %term%` would be trivial on a table of 5k rows (under 50ms), so hopefully it would be the same if I have a good index on a large table before doing it? Or is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: `LIKE '%format%'` cannot use an index.  If you really have a need to assert this condition quickly, then consider creating a materialized view.

Comment: Qualify your column names.  Without knowing where the columns come from, nothing can really be usefully said about performance.

Answer (score 1):

Two things. First, it doesn't matter how many *total* rows in the table, because the index on `user_id` will select only those rows for matching. As you say there are about 5k per user_id, then that's easily managed.

Second, `LIKE '%foo%'` will *not* use an index: the leading `'%'` precludes that. If you want to use an index, you'll have to accept a pattern of `LIKE 'foo%'`. If that fits the use case, then the query as written will perform fine.

If either of the above conditions doesn't hold, then consider using a dedicated search engine (like Sphinx, or [roll-your own with radix trees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22531268/2908724)) or materialize your search into a more indexable format (such as using [MySQL Full-Text Search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905273/2908724)).